# How to make a model has unlimited images with paperclip in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, paperclip

I have a User model that has an avatar. Paperclip was used to allow image upload. However, I want a User to be able to upload as many images as possible (unlimited) . How do I modify my model to allow such behavior ?
The user model looks like this:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :pic, styles: { medium: "420×633!", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :pic, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the `photos` (if you call it that) for a user in a separate model and add an association to it in `User` model:

**Command line**

```
rails g paperclip photo pic
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
```

**app/models/photo.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :pic, styles: { medium: "420×633!", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :pic, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the given specifications you could generate another model for saving user_images, in this way user can have unlimited images.

```
user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_images, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes :user_images

  validates_attachment_content_type :pic, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy 
end

user_image.rb
Class UserImage < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   has_attached_file :user_image, styles: { medium: "420×633!", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

Added accepts_nested_attributes in user_model and paperclip setting in user_image for uploading images.